# How do I collapse staggered data to one row in R by participant number and timepoint?

Tags: r, data-wrangling

My apologies if someone has asked this question before--I can't find it. I have a dataset where each survey completed is on its own row for each participant. There are ~10 rows per participant per timepoint. I need one row per participant per time point. Here is some test data:

```
x <- data.frame(time = rep("week_1",6), PartNum = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
                event = c(NA, "Survey_1", "Survey 2", NA, "Survey_1", "Survey 2"),
                S1Q1 = c(NA,3,NA,NA,1,NA), S1Q2 = c(NA,4,NA,NA,2,NA),
                S1date = c(NA,"2020-03-02",NA,NA,"2020-03-04",NA),
                S2Q1 = c(NA,NA,5,NA,NA,3), S2Q2 = c(NA,NA,3,NA,NA,2),
                S2date = c(NA,NA,"2020-03-02",NA,NA,"2020-03-04"),
                race = c(0,NA,NA,1,NA,NA), age = c(60,NA,NA,58,NA,NA))

    time PartNum    event S1Q1 S1Q2     S1date S2Q1 S2Q2     S2date race age
1 week_1       1     <NA>   NA   NA       <NA>   NA   NA       <NA>    0  60
2 week_1       1 Survey_1    3    4 2020-03-02   NA   NA       <NA>   NA  NA
3 week_1       1 Survey 2   NA   NA       <NA>    5    3 2020-03-02   NA  NA
4 week_1       2     <NA>   NA   NA       <NA>   NA   NA       <NA>    1  58
5 week_1       2 Survey_1    1    2 2020-03-04   NA   NA       <NA>   NA  NA
6 week_1       2 Survey 2   NA   NA       <NA>    3    2 2020-03-04   NA  NA
```

How do I get survey 1 and survey 2 and the demographic data all on one row for each participant and time point (Note: only one timepoint is shown in test data to save space)?

Desired results:

```
desired_x <- data.frame(time = rep("week_1",2), PartNum = c(1,2), S1Q1 = c(3,1),
                        S1Q2 = c(4,2), S1date = c("2020-03-02","2020-03-04"),
                        S2Q1 = c(5,3), S2Q2 = c(3,2),
                        S2date = c("2020-03-02","2020-03-04"),
                        race = c(0,1), age = c(60,58))

    time PartNum S1Q1 S1Q2     S1date S2Q1 S2Q2     S2date race age
1 week_1       1    3    4 2020-03-02    5    3 2020-03-02    0  60
2 week_1       2    1    2 2020-03-04    3    2 2020-03-04    1  58
```

I have read a lot of answers on this site, but this is my first question. Thank you for your patience and help this time around, and for the help you have given me unknowingly in the past.

Comment: That is a great first question. Is the missing structure following this structure over the whole dataset? (e.g. there is no more than 1 valid S1date per participant per week? or there might be multiple valid dates for the same week (and participant?)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have already eliminated repeat instances of the same survey for the same timepoint. There is only one valid date per participant per week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Edited: a simpler version that does not depend on custom functions

using `na.omit` to get only valid observations (per time/partnum)

```r
x %>% select(-event) %>% 
  group_by(time, PartNum) %>% 
  summarise_all(na.omit)
```

#### previous version:

The following will solve your question using dplyr:

```
x_clean <- x %>%                       # (1)
  select(-event) %>%                   # (2)  
  group_by(time, PartNum) %>%          # (3)
  mutate(across(.cols = everything(),  # (4)
                .fns = getmode)) %>% 
  distinct()                           # (5)
```

Each step can be understood as doing the following:
0) pick dataset `x`, and THEN

1. remove variable `event` from data set, THEN (read %>% as "and then"
2. group by `time` and `PartNum`, THEN
3. mutate across all (grouped) variables and get the mode of each (per `time` and
   `PartNum`. this will replace the `NA`s with the most common observation per grouping.
   if you stopped here, you would get repeated rows for each grouping, so finally
4. get only distinct rows from the resulting data set.
5. the resulting data set is assigned to `x_clean`

#### the whole code for reproduction

```r
## your data.frame
x <- data.frame(time = rep("week_1",6), PartNum = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
                event = c(NA, "Survey_1", "Survey 2", NA, "Survey_1", "Survey 2"),
                S1Q1 = c(NA,3,NA,NA,1,NA), S1Q2 = c(NA,4,NA,NA,2,NA),
                S1date = c(NA,"2020-03-02",NA,NA,"2020-03-04",NA),
                S2Q1 = c(NA,NA,5,NA,NA,3), S2Q2 = c(NA,NA,3,NA,NA,2),
                S2date = c(NA,NA,"2020-03-02",NA,NA,"2020-03-04"),
                race = c(0,NA,NA,1,NA,NA), age = c(60,NA,NA,58,NA,NA))


# helper function that works for numeric and character data
# will retrieve the most common value. 
getmode <- function(v, na.rm = TRUE) {
  if (na.rm) v <- na.exclude(v)
  uniqv <- unique(v)
  uniqv[which.max(tabulate(match(v, uniqv)))]
}

## solution 
library(tidyverse)

x_clean <- x %>%                       # (0)
  select(-event) %>%                   # (1)  
  group_by(time, PartNum) %>%          # (2)
  mutate(across(.cols = everything(),  # (3)
                .fns = getmode)) %>% 
  distinct()                           # (4)
x_clean
#> # A tibble: 2 x 10
#> # Groups:   time, PartNum [2]
#>   time   PartNum  S1Q1  S1Q2 S1date      S2Q1  S2Q2 S2date      race   age
#>   <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <chr>      <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 week_1       1     3     4 2020-03-02     5     3 2020-03-02     0    60
#> 2 week_1       2     1     2 2020-03-04     3     2 2020-03-04     1    58
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to get at what you are after is to first write a custom function to only return non NA values, and then use `dplyr` functions to summarize by time and PartNum.  Here is an example using your data

```
##Loading dplyr package##
library(dplyr)

##Example Data## 
x <- data.frame(time = rep("week_1",6), PartNum = c(1,1,1,2,2,2), event = c(NA, "Survey_1", "Survey 2", NA, "Survey_1", "Survey 2"), S1Q1 = c(NA,3,NA,NA,1,NA), S1Q2 = c(NA,4,NA,NA,2,NA), S1date = c(NA,"2020-03-02",NA,NA,"2020-03-04",NA), S2Q1 = c(NA,NA,5,NA,NA,3), S2Q2 = c(NA,NA,3,NA,NA,2), S2date = c(NA,NA,"2020-03-02",NA,NA,"2020-03-04"), race = c(0,NA,NA,1,NA,NA), age = c(60,NA,NA,58,NA,NA))

##Function to return only non-NA values##
fxn<-function(vec){
  out<-vec[!is.na(vec)]
  return(out)
}

##Summarizing the data using the new function##
#We'll want to get rid of the event column, hence the x[,-3]##
DF<-as.data.frame(x[,-3] %>% group_by(time, PartNum) %>% summarise_all(fxn))

##See the results##
DF

##Compare to your desired output##
y <- data.frame(time = rep("week_1",2), PartNum = c(1,2), S1Q1 = c(3,1), S1Q2 = c(4,2), S1date = c("2020-03-02","2020-03-04"), S2Q1 = c(5,3), S2Q2 = c(3,2), S2date = c("2020-03-02","2020-03-04"), race = c(0,1), age = c(60,58))

y
```

Good luck!
Take Care,
-Sean

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your solution works on the test data, but when I try it on my data set, it returns a data frame with 0 observations. Apparently the test data is not representative. I am trying to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: My guess is that you will have to tweak the `fxn()` function.  From the example data, I saw that basically the variable of interest would be recorded in exactly one row per participant, so removing all NA values would be a legitimate way to return all observations in a single row.  One potential reason you are getting this error might be the datatypes you are using in each column.  Would you mind posting the results of `str(X)` where `X` is your actual dataframe?